# SoftwareSerial response is semi-gibberish using ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, softwareserial

I have a working SoftwareSerial connection to my ESP8266 module on my Arduino UNO board. However, the response I get from the ESP8266 using the SoftwareSerial library is semi-gibberish.

So I do get the correct response, but some characters are changed.
For example when I ask the IP of the module, it sometimes returns the right IP, but most of the times just alters the IP, for example 092.168/123.5.

So what am I doing wrong?

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(10, 11);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.println("Started");
}

void loop() {
  if (esp8266.available()) {
    Serial.println(esp8266.readStringUntil("\n"));
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    esp8266.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

When I send the `AT` command, I sometimes get `OK□` or some other extra random characters.

So how do I make the SoftwareSerial show (or receive) the correct response?

Comment: You never call `begin` on software serial.

Comment: How do you convert logic level Arduino UNO (5V) and ESP8266 (3.3V)?

Comment: @AltAir, I don't, the board accepts a logic level of 5V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try lowering your baudrate to 9600.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2016/01/23/esp8266-wifi-with-arduino-uno-and-nano/

Comment: Thank you, however I tried chaning the baudrate to 9600 by sending ```AT+IPR=9600``` but I couldn't talk to it on rate 9600. I can't talk to it on any rate anymore... So what would the best way be to change that modules baud rate?

Comment: You need to send that command at the baud rate the ESP8266 is expecting. The default is 115200.

Comment: The command I used ```AT+IPR=9600``` bricked the flash, but I tried it on a different ESP8266, used the ```AT+CIOBAUD=9600``` and everything started to work! I can now read it without any gibberish, thanks!